# Effect Colour of Noise in Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to create a shader in Shader Graph that allows me to individually change the black and white channels of any Noise, similar to the Colour Ramp in Blender. I can multiply the noise by some colour, however that only effects the white part of the noise. What I want is to be able to individually effect both the black and the white part of the noise, so that I could turn some random black and white noise into, for instance, green and red. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the black in a specific color, you would run the noise through a one minus node(ostensibly getting an inverse noise), and then you can multiply it by a color and then add it together with the other colored noise of the non inverted that you managed.

The reason why you must use one minus is that when you multiply a color with your noise, the black is just 0, so multiplying anything with that just returns 0(ie black) .

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. Are you also able to tell me how I can then control the "hardness" of the noise - to fill out the black and white sections so that they are clamped to either 0 or 1?

Comment: Yep, so if you want it completely hard, either black or white you can use the Step node - but if you want some control, you can use the Smoothstep node. Just note that the Smoothstep takes 2 parameters, besides the (in this case) noise value, and makes a smooth transition between them, so the closer they are to each other, the harder the transition is. (for example inputting 0.4 and 0.6 might make a small smooth transition). But when you want to add this together with the non inverted value you will have do the same, but opposite, so the values line up and you dont get a gap.